# What is Application Insights: MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors

Tags: azure

One of the custom properties in Application Insights is MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors. What does it mean and is there any documentation on it?

Comment: It indicates whether a telemetry item has been processed by the metric extractors. It would be great if you that edit your question by providing more details like what you have tried and where you are getting this by providing any images then only community members can help you by providing detailed solution.

Comment: Vijaya, Where did you find information about the property?